# Failed to install android SDK tools 26.1.1 and Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Can't download and install android SDK tools 26.1.1 and emulator.

This is the log output :

```
To install:
- Android Emulator (emulator)
- Android SDK Tools (tools)
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 26.1.4)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4266726.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-4266726.zip': C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation07\emulator-windows-4266726.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 26.1.4)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation02\android\repository\sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
, response: 200 OK
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip': C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation02\sdk-tools-windows-4333796.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
, response: 200 OK.
"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Android Emulator (emulator)
- Android SDK Tools (tools)
```

Comment: Try open android sdk manager as Administrator

Comment: Couldn't open SDK manager even as administrator from SDK folder, it's just flashing.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me ..

1. Installed [java](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)
2. Run `Android Studio` as `Administrator`

Answer (score 1):

After Running `Android Studio` as `Administrator` solved my issue.

I am successfully able to download `sdk` now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection because it can't download package to install

Comment: I tried several times and still getting the same issue, other packages installed normally

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified , check above path and find same error, this is the first time i see it

Comment: my SDK Folder is in another location than default one, could this be the problem? but I never faced this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me on Mac after changing the destination folder from `/Users/.../Library/...` to `/Users/.../My Folder`

Answer (score 0):

try this

`flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`

- Make sure it has the following structure

`<sdk folder>/cmdline-tools/latest/`

`|- bin`

`|- lib`

`|- ...`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to use AVD manager to download & install the platform tools (my avd uses android 31):

```
sdkmanager "platforms;android-31"
```

to find out a list of available options run

```
sdkmanager --list
```